# I am using jmeter to test a javascript application

Tags: web, jmeter

I am using jmeter to test a javascript application. I need to create a different thread with a unique session for each user. Because in my application you can only have one login per user at a time so putting 100 times the same user I will not get to any conclusion. I have created 40 users user0,user1....user39 with the same password is there a way to automatically create simultaneous threads for each of them?

Comment: Run Jmeter script with 40 users/threads and replace username with csv data config to take new user for each thread.

Comment: any feedback on my answer ? if it was helpful it should be accepted and possibly upvoted so that it's helpful to others

Answer (score 0):

You should read this:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html

All you have to do is set in [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group):

- Number of Threads to 40
- Number of iteration to 1
- Use a [CSV Data Set](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) for the user name that will export a username variable, you will then be using ${username} in the HTTP Request parameters